# In RMarkdown and Shiny, how to wrap inputPanel and renderPlot in a unique call

Tags: r, function, shiny, r-markdown

Let's look at this code for a dynamic report,  it's basically the default template strip to the minimum:

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
inputPanel(selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20))
renderPlot({hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks))})
```
````

I would like to define a function `f1` so I can run this instead and have exactly the same output :

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
f1()
```
````

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the `code` chunk option.

Here is one way to make it work for my example (though in practice it'll be easier to feed a string directly):

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```{r}
f1 <- function(){
  inputPanel(selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20))
  renderPlot({hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks))})
}
```

```{r,code = as.character(body(f1))[-1]}
```
````